# Visual studio 2008 debug Error connecting to undo manager of source file "whatever.designer.ds"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

HI,

When i compile my vs2008 solution which is a web application in debug mode i keep getting message box displayed which says that it cannot connect to "whatever.designer.cs". Can anyone help me fix this as it is very annoying.

thanks
niall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a simple solution  which is

1) Right-click the designer file and select delete
2) Right-click the aspx file and select Convert to Web Application

which i got from 
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ErrorConnectingToUndoManagerOfSourceFileQuotwhateverDesignerquot.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I found a simpler solution here: http://development.thatoneplace.net/2009/03/error-connecting-to-undo-manager-of.html

Comment: +1 The trick is: "My experiment consisted of simply opening the designer.cs file, typing a character somewhere in the file, deleting the new character, saving the file and recompiling."